# How to resume an svn download?

Tags: svn

I was trying to download a very big package using svn. It got interrupted after about an hour due to internet connection failure. Now when I have restored the connection is it possible to resume the download from the point where it earlier left?
I used the following command to begin the download

```
cd ~/<your_working_dir> svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.3
```

right now the terminal window is still as shown

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as you have started the check out, subversion creates working copy meta data in the folder.

Thus, you can run `svn up <wc-dir>`. After a terminated operation however, you might need to run `svn cleanup <wc-dir>` first.

Comment: looks like resumed

Comment: I tried giving svn cleanup. The following appears on the screen
svn: In directory 'opencv_extra/testdata/cv/detectors_descriptors_evaluation'
svn: Error processing command 'modify-wcprop' in 'opencv_extra/testdata/cv/detectors_descriptors_evaluation'
svn: 'opencv_extra/testdata/cv/detectors_descriptors_evaluation/evaluation_test_description.txt' is not under version control

Comment: Which svn version do you have? You could probably delete that particular file manually and retry, but then we'll never know what went wrong.